# (Vs code: ) gcc: error: missing filename after '-o'

Tags: c, gcc, installation, directory, filenames

When I try to run any C file with Vs code I get following error:
gcc: error: missing filename after '-o'
I have no idea what that means so if you need more specific info just let me know.

I thought it might be because I didnt have the default builder task so I copied this one out of the internet:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
    {
    "type": "cppbuild",
    "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
    "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
    "args": [
    "-g",
    "${file}",
    "-o",
    "${filedirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
    ],
    "options": {
    
        "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin"
    },
    "problemMatcher": [
    "$gcc"
    
    ],
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
    },
    "detail": "compiler: \"C:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe\""  
    }
    ]     
    }
```

didnt change anything

Comment: The '-o' command line option is used to provide the name of the output file, the command line  "gcc -std=C99 -pedantic -Wall simple.c -o simple" would compile the file `simple.c` and place the resulting executable in the file `simple`.  The default output file name is "a.out" if you do not use the -o flag.  Note that the file name is required if you use the -o flag.  As always, the documentation for gcc (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.htm) should be your first stop for questions like these.